# How does Trello show users online/offline/idle state accurately?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, trello

Trello shows the information of online/offline/idle status very accurately as I personally saw. There are several solutions for tracking users online statuses, and to do so accurately requires a serious overhead. There are also the traditional problems of not knowing if a user closed the browser, disconnected etc. that cause inaccuracy in showing the offline/idle status. For a platform that does not have chat functionality (which, I believe, which would have taken the overhead of tracking users' status and therefore makes the task finally easy) how is Trello achieving this, albeit without much overhead?

Also Trello is able to detect disconnects and resume connection (not so smoothly though).

The Pushing and Polling layer of Trello is described [here](http://blog.fogcreek.com/the-trello-tech-stack/)

Comment: You may want to checkout [this](http://nodeup.com/fiftyfour) episode of NodeUp.  The developers of Trello are interviewed and discuss their approach to user presence detection in some detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each browser tab is considered to be a session, associated with one user.  Each session's activity level is tracked separately, with a user being shown with the highest activity level of all of its sessions (where active is highest, then idle, then disconnected).

Each tab periodically sends its current status to the server - every minute if it has a working WebSocket, every 5 minutes otherwise.  Current status is reset to active every time the tab gains focus, or there is a keydown or mousedown event.  It goes idle if it has been more than 5 minutes since the most recent of those events.  The tab sends a status of disconnected in the onunload event, but we don't depend on this.

Every time a session sends its status to the server, the server looks at all of that user's sessions to determine whether that indicates a change to the user's status.  If it does, it broadcasts that new status to every person watching every board that user is on (this goes through the same framework that the rest of Trello's instant updates go through, and is too complicated to explain here).

The server also checks each session to see if its been too long since we've heard from that session (2 minutes if its a WebSocket session, 10 minutes otherwise) and removes the session if it has been (removing a session indicates it is disconnected).

There are a couple of optimizations hiding in there, but that's the main story.

Comment: although not recommended as per SO, I would like to thank you for this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Trello using socket.io.. so when ever a user login it broadcast a message that user has logged in , then they show him as online.
Once he disconnects they send a message on socket again to show him offline.

Many realtime apps using socket.io for showing realtime activities.

Comment: Trello is no longer using `socket.io` (except to support older clients).

Comment: @AaronDufour I just pulled up their js and it's right in there: `This application uses other third-party javascript components
 distributed under appropriate licenses. For more information,
 see the following:
      ...
      socket.io.js  http://socket.io/
`

Comment: @jcollum The code is still in there, but its dead.  We wanted to be able to easily fall back to it if our new socket solution didn't hold up at scale, but it did.  I'm a Trello dev, for the record.

Comment: @AaronDufour I was giving just a idea. Socket.io is hard to scale on multiple dynos(clustered environment). So for large scale application either people manage their own socket server or they use some thirty party socket client. But all third party clients also work on top of sockets. My team is using Pusher as socket client.

Comment: @AaronDufour: Trello is nice app. Even my team using it. We are having so live activities like chat and real-time feeds. We built the solution over socket.io. But facing issues in scaling up as it is deployed on heroku. so app breaks if we deploy on multiple dyono. Now we are using using 'pusher'. Can you suggest better solution?